# charAt(0) in PHP

Tags: java, php, unicode

Hello I was wondering how I might go about getting the java equivalent of charAt(0) which returns a unicode numeric value between 0-1114112 for the character in question. All the code snippets I've found so far don't return the unicode values in this manner.

The reason this is vital is because I'm coding an encryption library that's been developed in autoit and java, and I'm trying to keep the data format interchangeable between programming languages.

Comment: Leaving [this (`mb_convert_encoding`)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) here as it *might* be helpful.

Comment: Can you give relevant example of output you're trying to have, the output you're getting, and the code leading to the output you're getting?

Comment: mb_substr (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) may help.

Comment: Not all unicode characters have a value in the range 0-1114112. Encrypted data is best exchange as a series of bytes in UTF-8.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the unicode characters in this script into their respective numerical index and revert them back to their original char from that index, see my code here https://github.com/pdglobal/DARTIS-PHP/blob/master/crypt.php as you can see I'm successfully converting the chars to and from their ascii values, but this is limited to the standard 256 chars, I'm looking for a way to get their unicode index in the same way that java does here in this code https://github.com/pdglobal/DARTIS/blob/master/src/DARTIS/crypt.java

Comment: and here is an example https://pdglobal.net/DARTIS/DARTIS.php I'm trying to allow for the encoding of unicode chars so that they can be encrypted and then decrypted to their original values, and I'm trying to use ints to represent them in the same way my java and autoit source does

Answer (score -3):

Found my solution using a unicode safe string split, found on the php manual website, and the mb_chr() and mb_chr() functions